# C concat two small strings to one larger string

Tags: c, pointers, concatenation, strcat

I am trying to create a program that will concatenate two strings together.
My code creates a `char[]` that is `strcat`-ed into by two strings. The result is confusing garbage. Any idea what's happening? I would imagine that the `char[]` is already filled with garbage when I try to `concat` it, but I'm not sure.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char* s1 = "this";
    char* s2 = "that";
    char s3[9];

    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        printf("%c\n", s3[i]);
    }
    strcat(s3, s1);
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        printf("%c\n", s3[i]);
    }
    strcat(s3, s2);
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        printf("%c\n", s3[i]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
@



@
t


@
t
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either have to set s3[0] = '\0'; or you must use strcpy for the first one.

s3[0] = '\0';

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char* s1 = "this";
    char* s2 = "that";
    char s3[9];
    int i;

    s3[0] = '\0';

    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        printf("%c\n", s3[i]);
    }
    strcat(s3, s1);
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        printf("%c\n", s3[i]);
    }
    strcat(s3, s2);
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        printf("%c\n", s3[i]);
    }
}
```

strcpy

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char* s1 = "this";
    char* s2 = "that";
    char s3[9];

    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        printf("%c\n", s3[i]);
    }
    strcpy(s3, s1);
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        printf("%c\n", s3[i]);
    }
    strcat(s3, s2);
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        printf("%c\n", s3[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I used a for loop to traverse s3 and set all values to \0. Is there some better way to create a usable empty string or is this the only way?

Comment: @GraysonPike You don't need to do all positions, just the first one.